# How to identify Tags in a Text

Tags: lucene

I'm trying to identify predefined tags in a text.

Tags could be
* Surgery

- Hand
- Gynaecology
- Ophthalmology
- Hand Surgery
- Arthropod-borne viral fevers and viral haemorrhagic fevers

etc

What I'm doing now, is retrieving the term vectors from the text and running individual that against the tag index. I have the following issues

- If I use a keyword query with wildcard, I get a lot of irrelevant hits. E.g. the text contains John was borne with a growth on his .... will match "Arthropod-borne viral fevers and viral haemorrhagic fevers"
- If I use a phrase search this problem is eliminated but now the tag "Hand Surgery" won't be matched because the terms only contain individual words.

I'm just wondering if there is a better way to approach this. I initially looped over all the available tags against the indexed text which works well but is pretty performance intensive.

Comment: Have you had a look to lucene-facet?

Comment: What I ended up doing was using the term vectors of the text and querying the tag index based on an OR query using all the available terms. It's not perfect but it sort of works. I'm thinking of adding a second pass of the resulting tags and matching them against the text to eliminate irrelevant part matches.